# Vim: How to use .config to dim lines that are not compiled in

Tags: linux, vba, visual-studio, vim, macros

When reading the linux kernel source code in Vim, is there any way to tell the editor that there is a `.config` file at a certain location, and that it is to dim lines that are within macro guards that cause it to not be compiled into the kernel?

If not, what do you do to solve the problem when reading source code? I use vim, ctags and cscope, but I end up looking into code that is not compiled into the final binary image as I had not noticed macro guards. Is there a way to avoid this?

[EDIT]

As an example, the `.config` file lets say I have the following config value.

```
...
CONFIG_TEST_BLAH
...
```

Later on, in one of the C files I have :-

```
#ifdef CONFIG_TEST_BLAH
void test () {
...
...
}
#else
void test() {
...
...
}
#endif
```

In this case I'd like the block of code inside the `#else` block to be intented or colored differently so that I know its not being compiled into the final kernel image.

[EDIT 2]

I believe editors such as Visual Studio allow for this to happen, I'm wondering if there is a way to do this with vim.

Comment: How about adding some example code that illustrates the problem. Good luck.

Comment: I've added in an edit that hopefully makes the problem clearer.

Comment: You may be better served at [Vi and Vim](http://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

The [ifdef plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=7) provides such dimmed syntax highlighting. You can define this in multiple ways. From its description:

> Provides highlighting for  #ifdef  #ifndef  #else  #endif  blocks, with the ability to mark a symbol as defined or undefined.
>   Handles nesting of #ifdefs (and #if) as well, but does not handle  #if defined().
>
> Supports vim_ifdef:  modelines and .defines (_defines for win16/win32s) files to specify defined/undefined symbols.
>
> use :Define   or  :Undefine      to dynamically specify defined or undefined sections.